# how to add array with key to database

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, pdo

I am looking a way to sort fields and get the sorting values with `name=sort[ID]`
and get this array with sort name :

```
Array ( [201] => 1 [247] => 2 [25] => 3 [200] => 4 [249] => 5 [183] => 6)
```

how should I get values and IDs and  `UPDATE` them ?

I have this pdo code but it not get index of arrays :

```
$sortArray = array(
    '100' => 1,
    '203' => 2,
    '325' => 3,
    '123' => 4
);
$pdoConn = new PDO(); // Add your connection string and so on here
$stm = $pdoConn->prepare('UPDATE mytable SET `sort` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
foreach($sortArray as $s){
   $stm->execute($s);
}
```

thanks

Comment: what will be the expected op ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
$sortArray = array(
    '100' => 1,
    '203' => 2,
    '325' => 3,
    '123' => 4
);
```

And what you want to do is to update a table in the database so that the row with id 100 gets the sort value 1, the row with id 203 gets the sort value 2 and so on.
This is how I understood your question and here is how you could do it:

```
$pdoConn = new PDO(); // Add your connection string and so on here
$stm = $pdoConn->prepare('UPDATE mytable SET `sort` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
foreach( $sortArray as $id => $sort )
{
    $stm->execute(array($sort, $id));
}
```

This will loop through the array, and update the column sort to the sort value, for the corresponding id.

Hope this answered your question.